Work email under iPhone’s settings> messages > send and receive
Why is my work address included as an account under my personal phone under settings>messages> send and receive? Does this mean my employer can see my personal text messages? How did work email get there? I did not put it there.
Additional details:
It is a Personal phone - Only installed is Microsoft one drive, teams, and outlook from employer. These were installed by me and logged into work email account on my personal device.
Additionally, there is no other certificate or account or anything under VPN settings. Also, under certificates, there is no option under certificate trust setting for turning on. Only specifies trust store version and trust asset version.
Did teams put my work address under iMessage send and receive option in settings? Can my employer see my personal texts?


Why is my work address included as an account under my personal phone under settings>messages> send and receive? Does this mean my employer can see my personal text messages?

Those aren’t accounts per se; they are the email addresses other people can use to reach you or you can send as. As long as an email account is added to your device, it’s automatically added to iMessage.
Your employer has no access to your messages whatsoever.
If you don’t want people to reach you through your work address, just tap on it; the check mark will be removed indicating you can’t be reached with people using that address

But the area that I am referring to with the work email is specifically for iMessages not any messages. Does what you say still apply? And how would I remove the work email if no longer in use?

Also, can you please clarify "if you dont want people to reach you through your work address, just tap it" I did not tap the work address active - yet it was active when I learned that it was on my system. I do not have the work address connected with the normal mail program on iPhone or with any account setup other than via Microsoft Teams, Outlook, and one drive on my phone.

If it is active, then does this mean that my bosses could theoretically see my personal text messages. So if the messages are sent via my phone number won't Imessage still report the outgoing texts to all users of the iMessage platform much the same way as iMessage on the Mac works if I am sending via my phone?

It’s in my answer.  They cannot access your messages
